# Categorical definition of subdomain

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $S$ a **subrng** of $R$.

> Definition 1.
>
> $S$ is a subdomain of $R$ iff $S$ is an integral domain
>
> Definition 2.
>
> $S$ is a subdomain of $R$ iff $S$ is an integral domain and $1_R=1_S$.

Which is the proper definition in categorical view? Definition 2?

Moreover, are they equivalent?

Comment: @ZhenLin: A nit-pick: $e^2 = e$ implies $e = 0$ or 1 in an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

These two definitions are equivalent.

Since $1_S\cdot 1_S =1_S\cdot 1_R$, $1_S(1_S-1_R)=0$.

Since $R$ is an integral domain, $1_S-1_R=0$.